# Selecting a random sample and creating a new column that identifies them

Tags: r

I am working with R.

I have a set of data that looks like this...

```
Condition  TargetWord             WordProduced        WPcondition                                                                   1          Target1                  table                 A
1          Target1                  word                  B
1          Target1                  chair                 A
1          Target1                  pole                  C
1          Target1                  skate                 D
1          Target2                  car                   B
1          Target2                  house                 A
1          Target2                  shoes                 A
1          Target2                  girl                  A
1          Target2                  life                  C
2          Target3                  computer              D
2          Target3                  ball                  B
2          Target3                  court                 F
2          Target3                  plane                 C
2          Target3                  sky                   D
2          Target4                  tree                  A
2          Target4                  five                  C
2          Target4                  help                  D
2          Target4                  shave                 A
2          Target4                  love                  B                                                  3          Target5                  table                 A
3          Target5                  word                  B
3          Target5                  chair                 A
3          Target5                  pole                  C
3          Target5                  skate                 D
3          Target6                  car                   B
3          Target6                 house                 A
3          Target6                  shoes                 A
3          Target6                  girl                  A
3          Target6                  life                  C
3          Target7                  computer              D
3          Target7                  ball                  B
3          Target7                  court                 F
3          Target7                  plane                 C
3          Target7                  sky                   D
3          Target8                  tree                  A
3          Target8                  five                  C
3          Target8                  help                  D
3          Target8                  shave                 A
3          Target8                  love                  B
```

Since conditions 1 and 2 have 10 observations and condition 3 have 20 observations. I need to select a random sample of 10 observations of the condition 3 in order to correctly compare them.

Therefore, I need a new column that identify them in a new column in order to later conduct different analyses. So, I think, I am not sure, that the remaining values of the condition 3 needs to be identify as NA's in order to exclude them of some analyses.

So, I need this new column because for some analysis it dosen't matter the amount of observations, but for some others, like a t-test it does matter.

Any help would be great.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would give you `TRUE`/`FALSE` values in `result` column -

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  add_count(Condition) %>%
  group_by(Condition) %>%
  mutate(result = row_number() %in% sample(n(), min(.$n))) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  select(-n)

#   Condition TargetWord WordProduced WPcondition result
#       <int> <chr>      <chr>        <chr>       <lgl> 
# 1         1 Target1    table        A           TRUE  
# 2         1 Target1    word         B           TRUE  
# 3         1 Target1    chair        A           TRUE  
# 4         1 Target1    pole         C           TRUE  
# 5         1 Target1    skate        D           TRUE  
# 6         1 Target2    car          B           TRUE  
# 7         1 Target2    house        A           TRUE  
# 8         1 Target2    shoes        A           TRUE  
# 9         1 Target2    girl         A           TRUE  
#10         1 Target2    life         C           TRUE  
# … with 30 more rows
```

For condition 3 you will get 10 random `TRUE` and 10 random `FALSE`.

`add_count` adds number of rows for each `Condition` so you will get 10, 10 and 20 for Condition 1, 2 and 3 respectively. For each `Condition` then we select `min(.$n)` rows which is 10 here since that is the minimum number of rows any group has.

Comment: Hello, can your explain what did you do within the mutate parenthesis. What I understand is the the add_count adds like a unique number to each observation. Then you group by condition. But I get lost on what is going on after "select = " within the mutate parenthesis. Also, what does the select(-n) does? Thanks for this.

Comment: `select(-n)` drops the column `n` that we added with `add_count`. To avoid confusion I renamed `select` to `result`. I also added some explanation of the code in the edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

The following code groups by Conditions and selects n (10) random rows from each group. If n is the smallest number from all groups you can compute that first and insert it into the final call.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(Condition) %>% sample_n(size=10)
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.